# How to export millions of rows from MySQL to CSV via PHP without exhausting memory?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, csv, dql

So I have this table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE table;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(15) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| unid  | char(9)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| rs    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which contains millions of rows:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|  9435361 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm willing to export all rows in a `.csv` file (I'm using `Symfony2.6`). This file is meant to be stored on the server (not downloaded) and later on, read by PHP.

**1st attempt**

I tried to make a huge request to select all at once ([as per this blog post](http://obtao.com/blog/2013/12/export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-symfony/)) but this has, despite the use of `->iterate()`, led to `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted` after having run for ~9s.

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);

    $results = $em
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->getQuery()
        ->iterate();
    $handle = fopen('/path/to/csv/file/', 'w');
    while (false !== ($row = $results->next())) {
        fputcsv($handle, $row[0]->toArray());
        $em->detach($row[0]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

**2nd attempt**

I retrieved the total of rows and then, did a loop to make the same number of queries to retrieve rows one by one. But after having written ~260K rows into the `.csv` file, PHP runs out of memory and throws the same error as above : `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted`.

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);

    $total = (int) $em
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')
        ->countAll();
    $csv = '/path/to/csv/file';
    $handle = fopen($csv, 'w');
    for($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++)
    {
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->findOneById($i);
        fputcsv($handle, $entity->toArray());
        $em->detach($entity);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

**3rd attempt**

I have thought of the use of the `exec()` function to run the MySQL command line that would export the table. However, my manager seems not to like this option.

---

So am I making a fool of myself thinking that dumping ~9.5M of rows using PHP into a `.csv` file is even possible? Are there any other way I'm not yet aware of?

Thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: You should be able to iterate through the records without holding all of them in memory at once. Try to bypass your framework and use the database connection directly.

Comment: Shouldn't the *2nd attempt* do exactly that job? eg. not loading all of them in memory at once by querying rows one by one?

Comment: It should, but apparently it isn't for whatever reason. I suspect its the framework's fault.

Comment: @D4V1D I think detaching the entity does not necessary free its used memory. Not Familar with EMs in php, but in Java the Object is still existing, it just becomes `detached` from the `persistence context`. Maybe you can try to explicit use `unset()` after detaching the entity?

Comment: I describe my opinion with PDO (I don't know Doctrine). Create statement, fetch it row by row `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {}` and save to file via fput, fputcsv or whatever stream. This should bypass memory exhaustion.

Comment: @dognose `unlink` deletes files...

Comment: @Vatev Yea, ment `unset()` ofc.

Comment: @D4V1D : I know you got answer. have you tried increasing `ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');` Since you have mentioned mem_limit as 1024M you got `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted` ?

Comment: @Makesh I didn't mentioned it but increasing PHP's memory limit was, of course, **not** an option to consider as it would have merely solved the problem (if possible at all).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than attempting to build the object-tree, you could directly try to select the result into a file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Something like

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/temp/mycsv.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM theTable;
```

This should leave the job up to mysql and bypass any php memory limitations.

---

As venca noted: In this case the user under which you are running the mysql service needs write permissions to the directory in question.

Comment: This is the probably the fastest option, but it will create the file on the database server. You might have difficulties retrieving it.

Comment: User under which is running mysql server would need write permission to the directory, you want to save the csv.

Comment: I was also thinking the same about why to involve PHP in this scenario. Thanks for the answer :)