# Exporitng mysql data into csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to export mysql data into csv file,but the problem is that the csv file shows the name of fields not the fields data in csv file.

Here is my php code

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

include"../connection.php";
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

$query = "SELECT 'claim_dateclaim','claim_clientname', 'claim_account', 'claim_contract', 'claim_parcelno', 'claim_refno', 'claim_datecollected', 'claim_coladdress', 'claim_colpostcode', 'claim_counsineaddres', 'claim_conpostcode', 'claim_retailvalue', 'claim_claimvalue', 'claim_protitle', 'claim_reason', 'claim_type', 'claim_repparcelno'  FROM tbl_claimdetail ";

$rows = mysql_query($query );

fputcsv($output, array('Claim Date Raised','Client Name','Account no','Contract Number','Parcel Number','Company','Claim Ref no','Collection Date', 'Collection Address','Collection Postal code','Consignee Address','Consignee Post Code','Retail value','Claim value','Product','Reason','Type','Replacement no'));

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);

header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename=discussdesk".date('dmY').".csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";

?>
```

And here is my csv file

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNh6.jpg
```

Comment: maybe instead of fputcsv($output, $row); use array_values($row)

Comment: Thanx for it ..but it not works

Comment: [Let MySQL do the job for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31471265/2788131).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
```

associative array will work with array_values

Comment: Thanx but same problem still appear

Comment: show what is inside $row variable, maybe you use wrong quotes in your query and instead of columns you selecting strings?